# Initializing an array in a object in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates, syntax

I'm currently learning C++ and I created a little array-class.

Problem: I can't initialize the array in the object with the constructor.

What do I need to write, to initialize this member? (I'm sure that something with the syntax is wrong.)

Code:

`ary.h`:

```cpp
template<typename T_datatype>
class ary {

private:
    T_datatype* T_dataptr;

public:
    ary<T_datatype>(T_datatype* T_ptr) : T_dataptr(T_ptr) {}
};
```

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "ary.h"

int main()
{
    ary<int> array_int = {2, 3, 4}; //is it something like that?...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add error message?

Comment: it says "syntax error, expected ;"

Comment: For which line? Please be as specific as possible. When in doubt just *copy and paste the entire message*.

Comment: Hint: Every line in a declaration requires `;`. When the compiler alerts you to problems like this check which line the error references and ensure it's properly terminated.

Comment: ok, but it's german:

error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ";" vor "<"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor you have implemented expects an `int*` pointer as input, but `{2, 3, 4}` does not decay to an `int*`, so no, the syntax you have shown will not work given the class you have implemented so far.

If you know the exact array size at compile-time, you could do this using [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead:

```cpp
#include <array>

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct ary {
    std::array<T, N> data;
    ...
};
```

```cpp
#include "ary.h"

int main()
{
    ary<int, 3> array_int1{2, 3, 4};

    ary<int, 3> array_int2 = {2, 3, 4};

    ary<int, 3> array_int3 = {{2, 3, 4}};

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, if you really want `ary` to have a pointer to some array data, you could declare an actual array first, and then pass it in to the constructor, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class ary {
private:
    T *dataptr;
    ...

public:
    ary(T* ptr) : dataptr(ptr) {}
    ...
};
```

```cpp
#include "ary.h"

int main()
{
    int data[] = {2, 3, 4};
    ary<int> array_int(data);
    ...

    return 0;
};
```

But consider giving your class a constructor that takes a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as input instead, and then have the class allocate its own array internally (just be sure to follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)), eg:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class ary {
private:
    T *dataptr = nullptr;
    int datasize = 0;

public:
    ary() = default;

    ary(const ary &src)
        : ary()
    {
        if (src.dataptr && src.datasize > 0)
        {
            dataptr = new T[size];
            datasize = src.datasize;
            std::copy(src.dataptr, src.dataptr+src.datasize, dataptr);
        }
    }

    ary(ary &&src)
        : dataptr(src.dataptr), datasize(src.datasize)
    {
        src.dataptr = nullptr;
        src.datasize = 0;
    }

    ary(T* ptr, int size)
        : dataptr(new T[size]), datasize(size)
    {
        std::copy(ptr, ptr+size, dataptr);
    }

    ary(std::initializer_list<T> l)
        : dataptr(new T[l.size()]), datasize(l.size())
    {
        std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), dataptr);
    }

    ~ary()
    {
        delete[] dataptr;
    }

    ary& operator=(ary rhs)
    {
        std::swap(dataptr, rhs.dataptr);
        std::swap(datasize, rhs.datasize);
        return *this;
    }

    ...
};
```

```cpp
#include "ary.h"

int main()
{
    ary<int> array_int1;

    ary<int> array_int2 = {2, 3, 4};

    int data[] = {2, 3, 4};
    ary<int> array_int3{data, 3};

    ary<int> array_int4{array_int2};

    ary<int> array_int5{std::move(array_int3)};

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

A better option is to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, and let it do all the work for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class ary {
private:
    std::vector<T> data;

public:
    ary() = default;

    // the copy/move constructors, copy/move assignment operators,
    // and destructor will be implicitly generated for you...

    ary(T* ptr, int size) : data(ptr, size) {}
    ary(std::initializer_list<T> l) : data(l) {}

    ...
};
```

```cpp
#include "ary.h"

int main()
{
    ary<int> array_int1;

    ary<int> array_int2 = {2, 3, 4};

    int data[] = {2, 3, 4};
    ary<int> array_int3{data, 3};

    ary<int> array_int4{array_int2};

    ary<int> array_int5{std::move(array_int3)};

    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the real world you would use `std::array` or `std::vector` directly. No need to build wrappers around it. Also why not suggest the most obvious solution? `struct Array { T data[SIZE]; }`

Comment: "*No need to build wrappers around it*" - that depends on the extra functionality you want to add to it. Encapsulation makes sense. "*Also why not suggest the most obvious solution? `struct Array {T data[SIZE]; }`*" - added.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor:

```
ary<T_datatype> ...
```

should be named simply:

```
ary ...
```

i.e. without the template parameter.

The line in main:

```
ary<int> array_int = {2, 3, 4};
```

is expecting either a constructor that gets three `int`s or a constructor that gets `std::initializer_list<int>` neither of them exist in your class.

Comment: This still won't compile. You can't pass a brace-init list to the constructor expecting a pointer.

Comment: Well, ok, guess we wait for the OP to post a new question for that error then :)

Comment: The `<T_datatype>` in the constructor is *unnecessary* but harmless.

Comment: @cigien I'll accept your knowledge of such things! However, both MSVC and clang-cl (set to use the "preview" C++20 Standard) accept it.

Comment: @AdrianMole Hmm, I'm fairly certain I heard this somewhere. gcc recently started giving an error, so I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63513984/can-class-template-constructors-have-a-redundant-template-parameter-list-in-c2) to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, C++ does not allow [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) - a feature of the C language that could be useful here. Instead, you will need to declare your array 'argument' to the constructor as a variable in its own right, then pass that to the constructor:

```cpp
int main()
{
//  ary<int> array_int = { 2, 3, 4 }; //is it something like that?...
    int data[] = { 2, 3, 4 };
    ary<int> array_int{ data }; // "data" will here decay into a pointer to its first element

    return 0;
}
```