# Can class template constructors have a redundant template parameter list in c++20

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, language-lawyer, c++20

As far as I'm aware, the following [code](https://godbolt.org/z/b9sqrq):

```
template<typename T>
struct S {
    S<T>();
};
```

is well-formed, even though the `<T>` in the declaration of the constructor is redundant.

However, on gcc trunk (but not on gcc10.2), with `-std=c++20` this gives an error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
    3 |     S<T>();
                 ^
```

The [code](https://godbolt.org/z/87b7dc) compiles on clang trunk with `-std=c++20`. Is this a bug, or is this a breaking change in c++20 that is yet to be implemented in all compilers?

Comment: "is well-formed" Sure? [class.ctor/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#1) As far as I can see, no production there allows for template parameters.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Well, if it *is* a change to the language, then you're not going to find the rule in the latest draft :) And if it was never well formed, why is it not ill-formed? No compiler seems to diagnose this for any version. Is it UB then?

Comment: What kind change do you have in mind? `<T>` was never allowed there. Compilers are not required to diagnose errors in uninstantiated templates. gcc and msvc diagnose it once the template is instantiated. clang doesn't but this seems to be an [unrelated bug](https://godbolt.org/z/sK74co).

Comment: I take my words back, apparently I don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There was a change, in fact. It's documented in the compatibility section of the C++20 draft.

> **[diff.cpp17.class]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/diff.cpp17.class#2) **Affected subclauses**: [class.ctor] and [class.dtor]
> **Change**: A simple-template-id is no longer valid as the declarator-id of a constructor or destructor.
> **Rationale**: Remove potentially error-prone option for redundancy.
> **Effect on original feature**: Valid C++ 2017 code may fail to compile in this International Standard. For example:
>
> ```
> template<class T>
> struct A {
>   A<T>();           // error: simple-template-id not allowed for constructor
>   A(int);           // OK, injected-class-name used
>   ~A<T>();          // error: simple-template-id not allowed for destructor
> };
> ```

Specifically, the wording delta is this:

> **n4659** - C++17 standard draft - **[class.ctor]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#1) Constructors do not have names. In a declaration of a constructor,
> the declarator is a function declarator of the form
>
> ```
> ptr-declarator ( parameter-declaration-clause ) noexcept-specifier attribute-specifier-seq
> ```
>
> where the ptr-declarator consists solely of an id-expression, an optional attribute-specifier-seq, and optional surrounding parentheses, and the id-expression has one of the following forms:
>
> - in a member-declaration that belongs to the member-specification of a class but is not a friend declaration, the id-expression is the injected-class-name of the immediately-enclosing class;
> - in a member-declaration that belongs to the member-specification of a class template but is not a friend declaration, the id-expression is
>   a class-name that names the current instantiation of the
>   immediately-enclosing class template; or
>
> **n4861** - C++20 standard draft - **[class.ctor]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class#ctor-1) A constructor is introduced by a declaration whose declarator is a
> function declarator ([dcl.fct]) of the form
>
> ```
> ptr-declarator ( parameter-declaration-clause ) noexcept-specifier attribute-specifier-seq
> ```
>
> where the ptr-declarator consists solely of an id-expression, an
> optional attribute-specifier-seq, and optional surrounding
> parentheses, and the id-expression has one of the following forms:
>
> - in a member-declaration that belongs to the member-specification of a class or class template but is not a friend declaration
>   ([class.friend]), the id-expression is the injected-class-name
>   ([class.pre]) of the immediately-enclosing entity or

As you can see, the wording changed. C++20 now requires the injected class name when declaring a constructor for a class template. `S<T>` is a simple template id that names a specialization. Inside a template, the injected class name is simply `S`.

This is part of addressing [CWG 2237](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2237.html).

Comment: Aah, so it is a breaking change then? It was allowed before, but it's not from c++20?

Comment: @cigien - It appears so. I'll see if I can dig up the specific reason for the change

Comment: Thanks, that would be great. Seems like a lot of code could break, so I assume there's a very good reason for it.

Comment: @cigien - Anyway, issue linked. I tend to concur with the reasoning in 2237. I personally haven't used or seen simple-template-ids used to define constructors outside of c++ quizes.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I was today days old when I discovered that this had ever even been valid syntax.

Comment: *where the ptr-declarator consists solely of an id-expression* rules out any template parameters, both now and then. An injected-class-name does not contain template parameters either; it can be used as a template id if followed by template parameters, but by itself it doesn't have any. (`S` is an injected class name, `S<int>` is not)

Comment: Oh, so the code is now invalid because it's not useful? Didn't realize there would be a breaking change just for that. But I like that. I wonder if I learned this syntax from a quiz. :p

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. - I suggest you read the "then" part more carefully. It explicitly allowed a *class-name* for templates, which includes simple template ids.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I don't know why I thought it was valid, must have read it somewhere. But it *was* valid, as the answer shows.

Comment: It looks like I don't understand what id-expression means. It does in fact allow a template-id.

Comment: @cigien: The “feature” was more or less [accidentally introduced](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1435) (a *class-name* can be a *simple-template-id*) in C++14, so there wasn’t much of a compatibility reason to keep something that was useless and suggested that it might be possible to supply template arguments to constructors explicitly.

Comment: Just stumbled across this because Qt uses this syntax (https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/thread/qfutureinterface.h#L472) and it causes otherwise inscrutable errors about "expected )".