# Explicit instantiation definition: constructor template of class template -- is it possible? (Clang versus GCC)

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, instantiation, explicit-instantiation

Consider the following class template:

```cpp
template <typename> 
struct S 
{
    template <typename T>
    void f(T) { /* ... */ }
};
```

It is possible to provide a [*explicit instantiation definition*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation) (or *declaration* via `extern template`) of both `S` itself and `S::f`:

```cpp
template struct S<int>;
template void S<int>::f<int>(int);
```

---

But what if instead of a regular member function template we had the exact same situation with a constructor template?

```cpp
template <typename> 
struct S 
{
    template <typename T>
    S(T) { /* ... */ }
};
```

According to Clang, it is still possible to provide an *explicit instantiation definition* for `S` itself, but not for the constructor:

```cpp
template struct S<int>;       // OK
template S<int>::S<int>(int); // ERROR (!)
```

> ```
> error: out-of-line constructor for 'S' cannot have template arguments
> template S<int>::S<int>(int);
>                  ^~~~~~
> ```

On the other hand, GCC seems to accept both definitions. See [this **live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/E6WKaejTe).

---

**Is a definition such as `template S<int>::S<int>(int)` legal, or is Clang correct in rejecting it?**

Comment: I think in general, GCC accepts a lot more stuff than Clang. Clang is usually a lot more stringent, though I think there was some option about allowing C++ "extensions" to the specs like the ones that GCC accepts.

Comment: No, the template argument list in the c'tor declarator-id is [not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63513984/817643) after C++20. Never really was meant to be valid before, but accidently became such for a while. This is tagged LL, so I dunno if you really figured out how fix the code, but `S<int>::S(int)` is valid as a declarator in the explicit instantiation. Actually, any c'tor where its template argument is deducible from the c'tor function argument can be explicitly instantiated.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: in my actually use case the template parameter of the constructor is not part of the function parameter list, as it's an `enable_if` constraint. Any luck there?

Comment: Sadly no. I suppose one option could be to make the constraint into an unused, defaulted, function parameter type (c++03, retro style). But that's a shot in the dark because I dunno the overload set, so it may not be pleasant either.

Comment: Can you edit your code to show the actual use case? I'm having a hard time understanding how you can have a constructor template that has a non-deducible template parameter and is nevertheless usable.