# Template specialization code compiles with std=c++17 but fails with std=c++20

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, c++17, c++20

I have below templated class and its specialized version.

```
template<class T>
class Nullable
{
public:
   Nullable( void *ptr = NULL ) : val(), hasValue( false ) {
      (void) ptr;       // Prevent unused parameter warning
   }

   Nullable( std::nullptr_t ) : val(), hasValue( false ) {
   }

   Nullable( const T &val_ )
      : val(val_), hasValue( true ) {
   }

   Nullable( const Nullable<T> &that ) {
      hasValue = that.hasValue;
      if( hasValue ) {
         val = that.val;
      }
   }

   operator T () {
      return Value();
   }

   Nullable& operator=( const Nullable<T> &that ) {
      if( this == &that ) {
         return *this;
      }

      hasValue = that.hasValue;
      if( hasValue ) {
         val = that.val;
      }

      return *this;
   }

   Nullable& operator=( const T &val_ ) {
      val = val_;
      hasValue = true;
      return *this;
   }

   bool operator==( const Nullable<T> &other ) const {
      if( ! hasValue || !other.hasValue ) {
         return hasValue == other.hasValue;
      }

      return val == other.val;
   }

   const T& Value() const {
      ASSERT( hasValue );
      return val;
   }

   void Value( const T &val_ ) {
      val = val_;
      hasValue = true;
   }

   bool HasValue() const {
      return hasValue;
   }

   void Unset() {
      hasValue = false;
   }

   String ToString() {
      if( hasValue ) {
         String ret;
         ret << val;
         return ret;
      } else {
         return "(null)";
      }
   }

private:
   T val;
   bool hasValue;

};


template<>
class Nullable<String>
{
public:
   Nullable<String>( const StringBase &v )
      : _val( v )
      , _hasValue(true) {
   }

   Nullable<String>( const char *c )
      : _val( c )
      , _hasValue( true ) {
   }

   Nullable<String>() : _hasValue( false ) {
   }

   Nullable<String>( const Nullable<String> &that ) {
      _hasValue = that._hasValue;
      if( _hasValue ) {
         _val = that._val;
      }
   }

   operator StringBase &() {
      ASSERT( _hasValue );
      return _val;
   }

   Nullable<String> & operator=( const Nullable<String> &that ) {
      if( this == &that ) {
         return *this;
      }

      _hasValue = that._hasValue;
      if( _hasValue ) {
         _val = that._val;
      }

      return *this;
   }

   Nullable<String>& operator=( const StringBase &val ) {
      _val = String( val );
      _hasValue = true;
      return *this;
   }

   bool operator==( const Nullable<String> &other ) const {
      if( !_hasValue || !other._hasValue ) {
         return _hasValue == other._hasValue;
      }

      return _val == other._val;
   }

   const StringBase& Value() const {
      ASSERT( _hasValue );
      return _val;
   }

   void Value( const StringBase &val ) {
      _val = String( val );
      _hasValue = true;
   }

   bool HasValue() const {
      return _hasValue;
   }

   void Unset() {
      _hasValue = false;
      _val.Empty();
   }

   String ToString() {
      return _val;
   }

private:
   String _val;
   bool _hasValue;

};
```

The class String is derived from StringBase. When I compile above code c++17 it compiles fine but with c++20 I face below error in specialized case of Nullable :-

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
  101 |    Nullable<String>( const StringBase &v )
      |                      ^~~~~
nullable.h:101:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
  101 |    Nullable<String>( const StringBase &v )
      |                    ~^~~~~~
      |                     )
nullable.h:106:22: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
  106 |    Nullable<String>( const char *c )
      |                      ^~~~~
nullable.h:106:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
  106 |    Nullable<String>( const char *c )
      |                    ~^~~~~~
      |                     )
nullable.h:111:21: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
  111 |    Nullable<String>() : _hasValue( false ) {
      |                     ^
nullable.h:114:22: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
  114 |    Nullable<String>( const Nullable<String> &that ) {
      |                      ^~~~~
nullable.h:114:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
  114 |    Nullable<String>( const Nullable<String> &that ) {
      |                    ~^~~~~~
      |                     )
```

Any pointers to resolve this error on c++20 will really be helpful.

Checked some differences for c++17 and c++20 wrt template specialization but this case doesn't fall in those differences explained.Tried compilation with gcc 11.1.0 .

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Without going into the merit of the question, isn't this a case for `std::optional<T>`? Sorry for the off topic.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63513984/can-class-template-constructors-have-a-redundant-template-parameter-list-in-c2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can class template constructors have a redundant template parameter list in c++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63513984/can-class-template-constructors-have-a-redundant-template-parameter-list-in-c2) (The simplified version of that answer is that **inside** the definition of `Nullable<String>`, use `Nullable` instead of `Nullable<String>`.)

Comment: Thanks @JaMiT.  It's the same issue.