Syntax restriction on constructors of template classes
When I define a templace class, I can write this (as less <T> as possible):
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo(){}
    Foo(Foo const&){}
    ~Foo(){}
};

Or this (as many <T> as possible):
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo<T>(){}
    Foo<T>(Foo<T> const&){}
    ~Foo<T>(){}
};

When I define the functions of the class, I can write this (less) :
template <typename T> Foo<T>::Foo() {}
template <typename T> Foo<T>::Foo(Foo const&) {}
template <typename T> Foo<T>::~Foo() {}

Or this (more) :
template <typename T> Foo<T>::Foo() {}
template <typename T> Foo<T>::Foo(Foo<T> const&) {}
template <typename T> Foo<T>::~Foo<T>() {} // Yes, even that

But I can't write this :
template <typename T> Foo<T>::Foo<T>() {}
template <typename T> Foo<T>::Foo<T>(Foo<T> const&) {}

The error (from gcc 13.2) is the following :
error: 'Foo<T>::Foo' names the constructor, not the type
error: and 'Foo<T>' has no template constructors

I don't understand this restriction. What is the reason ? And why only for the definition ?
Example here.

I don't know why gcc changed, but note that you don't really have a choice if you are looking at C++20 compatibility https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63513984/can-class-template-constructors-have-a-redundant-template-parameter-list-in-c2 - And my guess would be something in gcc that isn't protected by a is_stdcpp20 check

This was possible in-class by omission in standard, it was possible to use simple-template-id. Similarly you could use struct or class keyword in non-template in some compilers.
